# Perl select return "bad file descriptor" error

Tags: perl

I am trying to implement inter process communication using pipes and the `select` command. Here is a first try:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use IO::Select;
use IO::Handle;

my @rh;
my %childs;
my $numChilds=2;
$SIG{CHLD}='IGNORE'; #Reap childs automatically

for my $i (1..$numChilds) {
  pipe(my $pread, my $pwrite);
  push(@rh,$pread);
  $pwrite->autoflush(1);
  my $child = fork();
  if ($child==0) {
    runChild($i,$pwrite);
  }
  $childs{$pread->fileno()}={pid=>$child,id=>$i,i=>0};
}

my $sel = IO::Select->new( @rh );
while (1) {
  say "Running select..";
  my @ready = $sel->can_read;
  last if (! @ready);
  for my $fh (@ready) {
    say "Processing file descriptor ".($fh->fileno());
    chomp(my $line=<$fh>);
    my $fd=$fh->fileno();
    my $child=$childs{$fd}->{id};
    say "Got line: \"$line\"..";
    my $nmsg=($childs{$fd}->{i})+1;
    if ($nmsg==2) {
      $fh->close();
      $sel->remove($fh);
      say "Select count: ".($sel->count());
      say "Closed fh $child..";
    } else {
      $childs{$fd}->{i}=$nmsg;
    }
  }
}
say "Done.";

sub someSeconds { return int(rand(4))+3; }

sub runChild {
  my ($i, $pipe)=@_;

  sleep (someSeconds());
  print $pipe "Child $i says: A\n";
  sleep (someSeconds());
  print $pipe "Child $i says: B\n";
  exit 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Running select..
Processing file descriptor 4
Got line: "Child 2 says: A"..
Running select..
Processing file descriptor 3
Got line: "Child 1 says: A"..
Running select..
Processing file descriptor 4
Got line: "Child 2 says: B"..
Select count: 1
Closed fh 2..
Running select..
Done.
```

The problem is that the last message from child 1 is missing `Got line: "Child 1 says: B"`.

I run `strace prog.pl` which gave:

```
select(8, [3 4], NULL, NULL, NULL)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

on the last `select` call..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $fh->close();
  $sel->remove($fh);
```

You must first remove the file descriptor from the select and then close it. Once it is closed it is no longer valid (that is `fileno($fh)` will return undef) and cannot be removed. And if cannot be removed select will still try to select on this (invalid) file descriptor, causing EBADF.

Comment: Ok, but didn't I just do that?

Comment: Since you are doing a `$fh->close()` before you are doing are `$sel->remove($fh)` you are closing the descriptor before you remove it from the select. It must be the other way around.