# (fork / waitpid) Wait for a list of child processes but interrupt the wait every time a child finishes

Tags: windows, perl

I'm using `fork` to spawn a number of child processes that run several tasks in parallel. In my case it is not sufficient to simply wait on all child processes in a loop, because if the first process in my list is the last to finish then my `waitpid` call would block until that process has finished.

I want my `waitpid` call to wake up every time a process has finished. The reason is that I immediately want to inspect the finished child process's exit code to determine if the process was successful so I can cancel any child processes still running. In my case, there is no point in letting them continue (potentially for hours!) if any child process returns a non-zero exit code because that would indicate an error, and even a single error would make the whole undertaking pointless.

(EDIT: I know that that's not how `waitpid` actually works, but I'm looking for something like that.)

Now, I *could* do this by using a loop to call `waitpid` with the `WNOHANG` flag and then keep checking my child processes with sleep intervals between individual `waitpid` calls, but this solution seems like a hack. Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Comment: Did you try trapping SIGCHLD?

Comment: [`IO::Select`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Select) can also be used. See [Perl select return “bad file descriptor” error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581407/perl-select-return-bad-file-descriptor-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [wait](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html) function, it waits for a child process to terminate and returns the pid of the deceased process.

Comment: and sets `$?` to the exit code of the child process.

Comment: Form the link you posted: "... it waits for a child process to terminate and returns the pid of the deceased process, or -1 if there are no child processes."

Yes, sounds like what I need. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can trap SIGCHLD, something like this:

```
$SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    my $child;
    while ( ( $child = waitpid( -1, WNOHANG ) ) > 0 ) {
        warn("Reaped $child, exited with $?");
    }
};
```