# Python code to Perl

Tags: python, perl, popen3

I have a piece of python code, that I need to convert it to perl, but unfortunately I am not good in perl, so sorry if the question is simple.
I would like to check STDOUT and STDERR for a specific word. Here is the python code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("bmod -b " + beginTime + " " + job_id + "; exit 1;", 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

while p.poll() is None:
    err = p.stderr.readline().decode('utf_8')
    out = p.stdout.readline().decode('utf_8')
    if "changed" in err or "changed" in out:
        subprocess.Popen("echo rescheduling was successful!", shell=True)
os._exit(0)
```

I read some documentations and open3 function may work here, but for p.poll() part I am not sure what to use.

Comment: There are several ways to read output from an external process in Perl, but the simplest are [`qx()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx%2f_STRING_%2f), [piped `open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open%28%29-for-IPC), and [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny). For `qx` and `open` you'll have to redirect STDERR since you want to check both STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: `open3`+`select` is too low level. Use IPC::Run3's `run3` or IPC::Run's `run`.

Comment: @ikegami Should I use something like this to wait for the output? `$pid = run3` or `$pid =open3` `wait($pid,0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on if it is important to print the message `"rescheduling was successful!"`  immediately after a the line was printed from `bmod` (when `bmod` is still running) or if it is sufficient to print the line after `bmod` has exited.

The last case is a very simple to achieve in Perl, for example:

```
my $out = qx/bmod -b $beginTime $job_id 2>&1/;
say "rescheduling was successful!" if $out =~ /changed/;
```

Regarding the first case, if you need to print the message immediately (even before `bmod` has exited), first note that your Python script is probably not working correctly. The lines `p.stderr.readline()` will block the script until a line is ready to be read from `p.stderr`, similarly `p.stdout.readline()` will block the script until a line is ready to be read from `p.stdout`. So if `bmod` only prints to `stdout` and nothing goes to `stderr`, the script will hang at the first call to `p.stderr.readline()` and only return when `bmod` exits.

I am not sure how to do this correctly in Python, but in Perl you can use [`IPC::Open3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3) combined with [`IO::Select`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Select). See for example: [Perl select return “bad file descriptor” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581407/perl-select-return-bad-file-descriptor-error)

Also note: A simpler solution in Perl can be achived using [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) if `stderr` and `stdout` are merged:

```
my $pid = open ( my $fh, '-|', "bmod -b $beginTime $job_id 2>&1" ) or die "Could not run command: $!";
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
     print $line if $line =~ /changed/;
}
close $fh;
```